How to Make an Absolutely Positioned Div Responsive Across Different Screen Sizes?
I'm developing a website and have encountered an issue with making a div that is absolutely positioned responsive across different screen sizes. Here's the context and what I've tried so far:
Problem:
I have a header section in my HTML where I've positioned a "call to action" (CTA) div absolutely. This div contains several buttons. While the positioning looks perfect on one specific screen size, it doesn't adjust correctly when I resize the browser window or view it on different devices.
Code Example:
Here is the relevant part of my HTML and CSS:


<header class="min-h-[25vh] max-w-full relative">
    <div class="absolute top-[0px] md:top-[-155px] min-h-full">
        <video src="../../../videos/video-accueil.mp4" autoplay muted playsinline loop></video>
    </div>
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:space-x-7 items-center space-y-4 justify-around z-20 absolute bottom-[-300px] md:space-y-0 md:bottom-[-380px] left-0 right-0 mx-auto w-fit">
            <!-- Buttons here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>




The issue you're facing with the CTA div's positioning is because you're using absolute positioning with fixed pixel values (top, bottom) for different screen sizes. This approach can break responsiveness

yes but how fix ?

Make the parent container of your CTA div a flex container using display: flex in its class styles.Apply justify-content: space-around or your desired alignment (e.g., center) to the parent container. This horizontally positions the CTA div within the container based on the available space.

Here is the example base on your code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive CTA Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="background-video">
      <video src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fe4996602366316ffa06467/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4" autoplay muted playsinline loop></video>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-container">
      <div class="cta">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  </body>
</html>

Adjust Styles as per requirement and screen using below css
/* Style the header */
.header {
  min-height: 50vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
  position: relative; /* Required for absolute positioning */
}

/* Style the video background */
.background-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Ensure video fills the header */
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent video overflow */
}

.background-video video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Stretch video to fit container */
  object-fit: cover; /* Preserve aspect ratio (optional) */
}

/* Style the CTA container (optional for centering) */
.cta-container {
  display: flex; /* Make parent container a flexbox (optional) */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontally center CTA div (optional) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 67%; /* 80% from the top of the header (Adjust this as per needed Important) */
  bottom: 10%; /* 10% from the bottom of the header  (Adjust this as per needed Important) * */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2; /* Ensure CTA div is above background video */
}

/* Style the CTA div */
.cta {
  width: fit-content; /** adust if needed */
  height: fit-content; /** adust if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background */
  padding: 1rem; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  color: #fff; 

}

/* Style CTA buttons (adjust as needed) */
.cta button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #333; /* Adjust button color */
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Media queries for further adjustments (optional) */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .cta {
    /* Adjust styles for smaller screens (if needed) */
  }
}

